# Create SAS Data Step to import csv from pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, sas

I'm trying to create a string that I can copy and paste to import a dataframe into SAS where the opening and closing lines are static and the middle lines need to be adjusted based on the column names, name length, and the data types of the columns so that the result looks like:

```
data **infile** %let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */
infile **filepath** delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;
        informat A Best32. ;
        informat B Best32. ;
        informat C Best32. ;
        informat D Best32. ;
        informat E $11. ;
        format A Best12. ;
        format B Best12. ;
        format C Best12. ;
        format D Best12. ;
        format E $11. ;
                input A
                input B
                input C
                input D 
                input E $
;
if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */
run;
```

My current code omits a column. Depending on the input dataframe, the column that it omits changes. With a datafame of A,B,C, and D it leaves out D from the middle set of prints. With the addition of E, it leaves out C from the middle set of prints. From another dataset I have it leaves out the 4th of 5 columns from the first group of prints. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's what I have:

```
def sas_import_csv(df):
    '''Takes a dataframe and prepares a data step to import the csv file to SAS.
    '''
    value_fmts = [np.float,np.int32,np.int64]
    opening = '''data **infile** %let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */ 
infile **filepath** delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;'''
    closing = ''';
if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */
run;'''
    measurer = np.vectorize(len)
    dfLen = measurer(df.values.astype(str)).max(axis=0)
    print(f'{opening}')
    for l,col in zip(dfLen,df.columns):
        if df[col].dtypes in value_fmts: infmt = 'Best32. ;'
        else: infmt = f'${l}. ;'
        print(f'\tinformat {col} {infmt}')

    for l2,col2 in zip(dfLen,df.columns):
        if df[col2].dtypes in value_fmts: fmt = 'Best12. ;'
        else: fmt = f'${l2}. ;'
        print(f'\tformat {col2} {fmt}')

    for col3 in df.columns:
        if df[col3].dtypes in value_fmts: ct = ''
        else: ct = '$'
        print(f'\t\tinput {col3} {ct}')
    print(closing)

dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index=dates, columns=list("ABCD"))
df['E'] = "some string"
sas_import_csv(df)
```

Which gives this output that is missing column C in the format section:

```
data **infile** %let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */
infile **filepath** delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;
        informat A Best32. ;
        informat B Best32. ;
        informat C Best32. ;
        informat D Best32. ;
        informat E $11. ;
        format A Best12. ;
        format B Best12. ;
        format D Best12. ;
        format E $11. ;
                input A
                input B
                input C
                input D
                input E $
;
if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */
run;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Is your question how to generate SAS code to read a CSV file?  Something else?

Comment: @Tom Yes, I work with a dataset in python and then read it to a csv. To combine with other sas data, I want to automate the sas code to import the csv file.

Comment: To read a CSV file just use `data want; infile "filename" dsd truncover ; input A B C D E :$11.; run; `  Where WANT is dataset name to create and FILENAME is the input file's name.  A B C D and E ar ethe variables.  use the : prefix and an in-line informat for the character variables will allow to skip defining the length as SAS will guess to use the width of the informat as the length. No need for those INFORMAT or FORMAT statements.  Numeric variables do not need informats.  If you have data, time or datetime then you will need informats and formats.

Comment: can you show the definiiton of the data frame you are trying to export to a CSV file?   Do you want to use the metadata from the data frame to define how to create the variables in SAS? Or do you have some other source of metadata (like a different data frame) that defines how the variables should be defined in SAS?

Comment: @Tom, the issue in SAS that I was facing is that when it guessed the character length, it would use the first 200 obs to make the guess, unless I told it to use all of the observations which would then take too long. Character lengths can change and so importing trimmed the string for the values at the bottom of the dataset. This gives me a way to find the maximum length of a string in a column and yeah it would be nice to get the metadata and pull date formats as well, but the character length was my issue

Comment: So you are probably talking about PROC IMPORT (it is the source of that ugly coding style).  You can tell it to read the whole file by using the GUESSINGROWS statement before selecting a length for the character variables.  Or use some other tool to guess how to read the file. But if you KNOW how the variables should be defined then use that to write the program.  But guessing from the length of what it in your dataframe it not really any better than guessing from the length in the CSV file.

Comment: @Tom Yes, that is what I'm trying to do with this python program is to create a datastep that imports the csv file in the format that I want using the data from the dataframe dtypes and maximum string length. The dataframe I was working with has 500,000 observations and these were the main variables I was working with to import with the right format 'Ticker: $11. , ReportID: Best32. , PubDate DATE11.  , Title $46. ; Organization $46. ; Author $45. ;'

Comment: So to READ the CSV file you need to use INFORMATs. BEST is a FORMAT. To read that list use:  `input Ticker :$11. ReportID PubDate :date. Tile :$46. Organization :$46. Author :$45.;` and add a format statement for the date variable. `format PubDate date11.;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243805/discussion-between-j4ffle-and-tom).

Comment: Bit surprised this isn't a method in Pandas, but looks like it's not.

Comment: the loops are very basic to miss anything out. I suspect that one of the columns was an `index` instead of a column field. you could try rerunning with `df.reset_index()`.

Comment: @samkart thanks for the suggestion, but that wouldn’t explain why it only skips that column in one of the three loops. All three loops iterate over the same data - so really  i should have only had the one loop to begin with

Comment: interesting. however, I'm not able to replicate the issue on my end. Was the issue persistent? as in it occurred every time you used your func?

Comment: @samkart yeah. It was persistent and happened with data frames of different sizes and column types. Interesting you were not able to replicate it. I found a better solution to what I was trying to do, but still confused about this behavior. Was wondering if it was something about looping over the same content multiple times

Comment: @samkart turns out when I run it in VS code terminal I have the issue. When I run it in an interactive session, it works fine. I wonder if it is something about trying to print to the terminal using loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't answer the question of why the loop wasn't printing in the one instance, but it is a much better way to do what I was originally trying to do anyway. Thanks @Tom for the guidance.

```
from pandas.api.types import is_datetime64_any_dtype as is_datetime, is_object_dtype as is_object

def sas_import_csv(df,sas_date_fmt='yymmddn8.',filePath='',outName = 'X'):
    '''Takes a dataframe and prepares a data step to import the csv file to SAS.
    '''
    value_fmts = [np.float,np.int32,np.int64]
    opening = f"%let infile = '{filePath}';\ndata {outName}; %let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */ \ninfile &infile delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD TRUNCOVER lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;"
    inp = 'input '
    fmt = 'format '
    infmt = 'informat '
    closing = "if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */\nrun;"
    measurer = np.vectorize(len)
    dfLen = measurer(df.values.astype(str)).max(axis=0)
    for l,col in zip(dfLen,df.columns):
        if is_object(df[col]): inp = inp + f'{col} :${l}. '
        elif is_datetime(df[col]): 
            inp = inp + f'{col} '
            fmt = fmt + f'{col} {sas_date_fmt} '
            infmt = infmt + f'{col} yymmdd10. '
        else: inp = inp + f'{col} '
    return f'{opening} {inp} ;\n{fmt} ;\n{infmt} ;\n{closing}'
```

Now you can read the dataframe into SAS by simply copying and pasting the output from `print(c)` after running the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index=dates, columns=list("ABCD"))
df['E'] = "some string"
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns = {'index':'Date'})
f = r'C:\\Users\\user\\example.csv'
c = sas_import_csv(df,filePath=f)
df.to_csv(f,index=False)
print(c)
```